# Case statement with a contains

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, contains

This is a follow on from the below forum post:
[Case statement with contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129936/case-statement-with-contains/44135604#44135604)

I do apologise that I am writing a new post but I realised I missed out a lot of key information in my first forum post and if I added this on, this would confuse matters so thought I would just start over.

(I am using SSMS 2016)

---

I have got the below SQL code:

```
select
    ContactGroupType.GroupID,FormattedName,GroupName,FormattedName,ContactGroupType.GroupType,[Address]
from ContactGroupContacts
    left join ContactGroupType on ContactGroupContacts.GroupID = ContactGroupType.GroupID
    left join ContactContacts on ContactGroupContacts.ContactID = ContactContacts.ContactID
    left join ContactGroup_Details on ContactGroupType.GroupID = ContactGroupDetails.GroupID
    left join Addresses on ContactGroupDetails.AddressID = Addresses.AddressID
    left join ContactGroups on ContactGroupType.groupID = ContactGroups.groupID
where 
    ExpiryDate is null and
    [Address] in ('9 fox ave','10 bush')
order by
    FormattedAddress,
    grouptype asc
```

With the above code, I am getting the below results:

```
    Group_Ref   |     GroupName     |   Contact_Name   |   GroupType     |   Address
     17766         MR D & N Goodwin     Dan Goodwin      Current Tenant      10 bush
     17766         MR D & N Goodwin     Nikki Goodwin    Current Tenant      10 bush
     17108         MRS A & P Bamer      Amber Goodwin    Current Tenant      9 fox ave
     17108         MRS A & P Bamer      Peter Goodwin    Current Tenant      9 fox ave
     2018          MR O & E Tofu        Ola Tofu         Former Tenant       9 fox ave
     11875         MR D & N Biggs       Dan Biggs        Former Tenant       9 fox ave
     12952         MR R & E Spur        Richard Spur     Former Tenant       9 fox ave
     13193         MS N & E Snalles     Nicole Snalles   Former Tenant       9 fox ave
```

I need to write a case statement to show the following. So whenever an address has one or more current tenants ONLY, I need to show a '1'. If the address has one or more current AND former tenants, I need to show a '2'. please see below:

```
    Group_Ref   |     GroupName     |   Contact_Name   |   GroupType     |   Address   |   Case
     17766         MR D & N Goodwin     Dan Goodwin      Current Tenant      10 bush         1
     17766         MR D & N Goodwin     Nikki Goodwin    Current Tenant      10 bush         1
     17108         MRS A & P Bamer      Amber Goodwin    Current Tenant      9 fox ave       2
     17108         MRS A & P Bamer      Peter Goodwin    Current Tenant      9 fox ave       2
     2018          MR O & E Tofu        Ola Tofu         Former Tenant       9 fox ave       2
     11875         MR D & N Biggs       Dan Biggs        Former Tenant       9 fox ave       2
     12952         MR R & E Spur        Richard Spur     Former Tenant       9 fox ave       2
     13193         MS N & E Snalles     Nicole Snalles   Former Tenant       9 fox ave       2
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This works in SQL Server and it should work in both MySql and Oracle:

http://rextester.com/TID50546

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (GroupType VARCHAR(20), Address VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (GroupType, Address) VALUES ('Current Tenant', '10 bush');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (GroupType, Address) VALUES ('Current Tenant', '10 bush');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (GroupType, Address) VALUES ('Current Tenant', '9 fox');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (GroupType, Address) VALUES ('Former Tenant', '9 fox');

SELECT A.GroupType
     , A.Address
     , CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B.GroupType) FROM TEST_TABLE B WHERE B.Address = A.Address GROUP BY B.Address) = 1 THEN '1'
       ELSE '2' END
FROM TEST_TABLE A
GROUP BY GroupType, Address;
```

---

```
SELECT
  ContactGroupType.GroupID
, FormattedName
, GroupName
, FormattedName
, ContactGroupType.GroupType
, A.Address
, CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CGT.GroupType)
               FROM ContactGroupType CGT
          LEFT JOIN ContactGroupDetails CGD
                 ON CGD.GroupID = CGT.GroupID
          LEFT JOIN Addresses B
                 ON B.AddressID = CGD.AddressID
              WHERE B.Address = A.Address
           GROUP BY B.Address) = 1 THEN '1'
       ELSE '2' END
FROM ContactGroupContacts
LEFT JOIN ContactGroupType 
       ON ContactGroupContacts.GroupID = ContactGroupType.GroupID
LEFT JOIN ContactContacts 
       ON ContactGroupContacts.ContactID = ContactContacts.ContactID
LEFT JOIN ContactGroup_Details 
       ON ContactGroupType.GroupID = ContactGroupDetails.GroupID
LEFT JOIN Addresses A
       ON ContactGroupDetails.AddressID = A.AddressID
LEFT JOIN ContactGroups 
       ON ContactGroupType.groupID = ContactGroups.groupID
WHERE
    ExpiryDate IS NULL AND
    A.Address IN ('9 fox ave','10 bush')
ORDER BY
    FormattedAddress
  , grouptype asc
```

Comment: Hi Jake, how would you do this? Because the address and the current/former tenants are from 2 seperate tables. I am pasted the code into my original post.

Comment: I have edited my post. Try the second bit of SQL there and see if you get the desired results.